# Android AVD with lower API level

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

A bit of a silly question, but I am trying to play around with supporting different Android API levels and created a simple application which has the following SDK version settings:

```
    <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
```

I have a device to test on which has the latest version installed, but when I am trying to create AVD with lower version API I can't choose any other option apart from the latest one (18) as nothing is available in the list. I've tried a variety os sample devices with no luck. How can I create an AVD with API level 8 or 10?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download that sdk level and emulators for the level from the Android SDK manager. If the sdk is set up properly, simply type `android` in the command prompt and it should show up.

Comment: If you use the eclipse SDK manager you need to restart Eclipse to see the newly installed target.

Answer (score 2):

Download:

- Sdk platform
- System image

  for API you want to use from Android SDK manager.